# Join column content by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I'm trying to find a way to get and combine the column contents that shares the same attribute value of "headers".

I'm working with jquery and experimenting with "$.map" (which I've never used before) - but I can't really figure out how to get the end result I want.

I have a table similar to this one (I have no way of changing the HTML since it's generated by the CMS):

```
<table>
<thead>
 <th id="randomheadid1">column head 1</th>
 <th id="randomheadid2">columnhead 2</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td headers="randomheadid1">content 1</td>
   <td headers="randomheadid2">content 3</td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
   <td headers="randomheadid1">content 2</td>
   <td headers="randomheadid2">content 4</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

... and I'd desire the result to be something like:

```
 <tr>
   <td headers="randomheadid1">content 1 content2</td>
   <td headers="randomheadid2">content 3 content4</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var $trs = $('table tbody tr');

$trs.first().find('td').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        header = $this.attr('headers');
    $this.append($trs.slice(1).find('td[headers="' + header + '"]').contents())
});
$trs.slice(1).remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ajJE9/)